# How to unrmarshal JSON that contains ints, floats and strings of numbers?

Tags: json, go

I have a multiple different JSON requests of data that is being passed into my Go app that contains numbers in different formats. An example of a request is as follows:

```
{
    "stringData":"123456",
    "intData": 123456,
    "floatData": 123456.0
}
```

Is there a way to unmarshal this data into the type which is determined by the JSON data. For example, string data would be "123456", int data would be 123456 and float data would be 123456.0. I do not have structs defined for these JSON objects and creating structs for these are not an option.

I have looked at the decoder.UseNumber() method to convert the data into strings, but I don't know how to handle the difference between stringData and intData after that.

Comment: Why isn't defining structs an option? That's how you specify types for fields. Otherwise the numbers will be `float`s and the string will be `string` (since JSON is a subset of JavaScript and all JavaScript numbers are floats, the default numeric type is `float`).

Comment: The JSON data being passed in does not have a static structure. This Go app will need to handle JSON data of different names, structure and sizes.

Comment: If you can't use structs then use a map of `json.Number`. https://play.golang.org/p/vuo8KZekcZG

Comment: @mkopriva `json.Numer` is `float`. OP wants numbers with no fractional component to come through as `int` (which isn't possible without defining a type).

Comment: The key names in the question are just examples, the application should be able to handle data with different key names and different types of data. If this is unable to be done, that's fine too, just wondering if there was a way.

Comment: In the JSON, if the value is surrounded by double quotes, it should be a string, without double quotes and without a decimal point would be an int, and anything without double quotes and with a decimal point would be a float, like the example. The key can be any arbitrary string.

Comment: And what type should be used for i.e. `0.3` which cannot be represented in a float? Or `9999999999999999999999999999999999999999999` which is too big for an int? What you try to do looks innocent, but does not work out well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Decode to `map[string]interface{}` with the [UseNumber](https://godoc.org/encoding/json#Decoder.UseNumber) option. Use a [type assertion](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Type_assertions) to find numbers and convert based on presence of the ".".

```
dec := json.NewDecoder(r)
dec.UseNumber()

var m map[string]interface{}
err := dec.Decode(&m)
if err != nil {
    log.Fatal(err)
}

for k, v := range m {
    v, err := decodeValue(v)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
for k, v := range m {
    v, err := decodeValue(v)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
    switch v := v.(type) {
    case string:
        fmt.Printf("%s is a string with value %q\n", k, v)
    case int64:
        fmt.Printf("%s is a integer with value %d\n", k, v)
    case float64:
        fmt.Printf("%s is a float with value %f\n", k, v)
    default:
        fmt.Printf("%s is a %T with value %v\n", k, v, v)
    }
}


...

func decodeValue(v interface{}) (interface{}, error) {
    if vv, ok := v.(json.Number); ok {
        if strings.Contains(vv.String(), ".") {
            return vv.Float64()
        } else {
            return vv.Int64()
        }
    } else {
        return v, nil
    }
}
```

[Run it on the playground](https://play.golang.org/p/qgDhXGrW7tR).

This example prints what's found and exits the program on error. If your goal is to create a map with the values of the correct types, then replace the code that prints numbers with `m[k] = n`.

Answer (score 1):

You can unmarshal the json to a map[string]interface{} and then cast to the correct types using a [type switch](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Type_switches).

Comment: How would it be possible to distinguish two different key-value pairs that have a string and an identical int or float? For example, if my data set is `{"data1":"123456", "data2": 123456}`?